# Python dynamic argument processing inside fucntion

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, tuples

I have following code that is not working.

```
def myFunction(*args):

    total_lists = len(args)

    for n in range(total_lists):
        print(list(zip(args[0], args[1])))


myFunction([1,2,3],["a", "b", "c"])
```

Basically function receives unknown number of arguments as `lists` with equal number of values, need to output every list line by line like so

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

if called with three arguments then

```
myFunction([1,2,3],["a", "b", "c"], ["one", "two", "three"])
```

should output

```
1,a,one
2,b,two
3,c,three
```

I don't have control how many lists will be passed to function so i can't mix them prior to sending, only can process inside function, how i make it work dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip(*args)`:

```py
def my_function(*args):
    for p in zip(*args):
        print(list(p))


my_function([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
```

Prints:

```
[1, 'a', 1.1]
[2, 'b', 1.2]
[3, 'c', 1.3]
```

Comment: Any reference from Python manual to what the star inside function parameters does exactly?

Comment: @RomanToasov Here it is described more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-do-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-mean-in-a-function-call . In function call it basically means to unpack parameters. Here `zip(*args)` becomes `zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3])`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output as strings as in your example you could use:

```
def myFunction(*args):
    z = zip(*args)
    for v in z:
        print(','.join((str(i) for i in v)))

myFunction([1,2,3],["a", "b", "c"], ["one", "two", "three"])
```

to give

```
1,a,one
2,b,two
3,c,three
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def myFunction(*args):

    total_lists = len(args[0])
    lst = []
    
    for i in range(total_lists):
        sub = []
        for j in range(len(args)):
            sub.append(args[j][i])
        lst.append(sub)

    return lst
        
r =  myFunction([1,2,3],["a", "b", "c"])
print(r) #Output: [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]

r = myFunction([1,2,3],["a", "b", "c"], ["one", "two", "three"])
print(r) #Output:[[1, 'a', 'one'], [2, 'b', 'two'], [3, 'c', 'three']]
```

Comment: Thanks, but agree its way more code than using `zip()`